# What game does this Character sheet belong to?

Tags: product-identification, character-sheets

I spotted a character sheet in someone's character folder, which looked rather interesting. It has a rather interesting cursive script and... I guess it's Art Deco decorative strokes added to it, then some kind of female face in the upper left corner. Luckily, after looking through the game gallery, there was a photo of the sheet on a photo they took, which I liberated from the handwriting so I could show it.

On the sheet:

- At the top: Name, Race, Bennies, Connections, Languages, Factions
- "Attributes": Agility, Smarts, Spirit, Strength, Vigor
- "Skills"
- "Gear", with total weight, weight limit, and penalty
- "Power", with PP, range, and duration ("dur.")
- "Weapons", with range and damage. On one line it says "reach 2, STR+d4" for the range and damage

[image: A snapshot of the sheet]

What game does this sheet belong to?

Comment: [Please don't answer in comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/33569) If you know the answer to the question, please post an answer instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By the name of the Attributes, the use of Bennies, skills  and powers looks like some kind of home made Savage Worlds sheet. Clearly with a Victorian theme so my first guess is the Rippers setting.

Comment: It's not the default Rippers one, just checked my copy.

Comment: As I was told by the owner today: Its Rippers Resurrected, and a custom sheet.

Answer (score 21):

### The game system itself is [Savage Worlds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savage_Worlds)

Having attributes of Agility, Smarts, Spirit, Strength, and Vigor, as well as having Bennies, the sheet is definitely from a Savage Worlds system. Compare to [this sheet](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/264226/Savage-Worlds-Adventure-Edition-Character-Sheet) from drivethrurpg.

However, Savage Worlds is a generic system (like [Powered by the Apocalypse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powered_by_the_Apocalypse) or [Forged in the Dark](https://bladesinthedark.com/forged-dark)) and it's unclear what *specific* Savage Worlds game this is; every one I've seen uses a number of checkboxes (representing the specific die to roll) for the attributes, for instance.